# Docker Build Error: Command Timed Out After 300 Seconds Nest.js app

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, nestjs, github-actions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm encountering an error while building my Docker image for my application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Here are the error details:

```
2024/03/13 08:40:16.565465 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to build docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/ failed with error Command timed out after 300 seconds
```

In an effort to resolve the timeout issue encountered during Docker image building for my application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I attempted to implement the following solution:

I created a file named .ebextensions/extend-time.config with the following contents:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 1000
```

But this have done nothing...